# How do you customize the log directory?

Tags: magento

I'm trying to customize my Magento's log directory, by setting `log_dir` in the Mage::app() $options, but it's still logging to `var/log/file.log`.

Note: I couldn't find this information very readily on SO or the web in general, so I felt it needed to be SO'd.

Comment: Sweet, wasn't sure how this whole answer-your-own-question business worked here, but I guess it really is encouraged!  Thanks for the upvotes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that (as of 1.6.2.0 at least), Magento doesn't actually use the `Mage::getBaseDir('log')` within it's log() method - weak sauce, right?

It uses `Mage::getBaseDir('var')` and appends `log` and then the file name that you pass in.

If you want to customize the directory more than that, you have to get your hands a little dirty.  For example, in our case, we wanted the log directory to be:

```
var/username/log/file.log
```

So here's how you bust it.  Drop this in your config.xml to tell Magento about your new logging class:

```
    <log>
        <core>
            <writer_model>Name_Module_Model_Zend_Log_Writer_Stream</writer_model>
        </core>
    </log>
```

Then, create a model:

```
class Name_Module_Model_Zend_Log_Writer_Stream extends Zend_Log_Writer_Stream
```

Then, proceed to do what you needs to do.  In my case, it went something like this:

```
public function __construct($streamOrUrl, $mode = NULL)
{        
    $newLogPath = $this->_workMyMagicOnLogFilePath($streamOrUrl, $mode);

    return parent::__construct($newLogPath, $mode);
}
```